# Using SVN in Windows (Wordpress plugin-repository)?

Tags: windows, svn, version-control, wordpress

I just got approved to Wordpress' plugin-repository. Howvere, they gave me access, but I have no idea about how to use it. Could someone explain me patiently, how can I use this repository to post my plugin?

I'm using Windows.

Martti laine

Answer (score 1):

- [Use TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/).
- [Read Practical guide to subversion on Windows with
     TortoiseSVN](http://www.shokhirev.com/nikolai/programs/SVN/svn.html).
- [Read How to Use
     Subversion (on WordPress.org, geared
     to plugin authors)](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/about/svn/).
- If you're totally new to version control software, read about [revision control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control).

Best of luck!

Comment: If you are using Total Commander, read [this](http://tortoisesvn.net/node/32), too.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it's very simple to go.

**Follow my steps**

1. Install TortoiseSVN (as we need some SVN clients).
2. Create a directory with the structure of **Assets, Tags, and Trunk**.
3. Create a folder inside of tags with the version number (for example 1.0.0).
4. Copy your Plugin file and readme.txt into it.
5. Create a Banner and Icon for the Plugin and place it in Assets Folder.
6. Image sizes should be the same as implied by the names. That is, banner-772x250.png should be 772 pixels wide by 250 pixels high. Similarly, icon-256x256.png should be a 256×256 square.
7. You can place the same Plugin File and readme.txt also into Trunk as per [WordPress Guidelines](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-org/how-to-use-subversion/).
8. Inside this Folder, Right Click (if you are using windows) and click SVN Commit, and give the SVN URL which WordPress provided to you in the email.

You are done! Your changes will be live within 72 hours. Most probably it will be done within a few hours. ***Congrats on your New Plugin!***